# How do I install a previous version of PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova

I updated to Cordova 3.4 and it is a nightmare for my current project. I would like to go back to Cordova 3.3 but I do not know the CLI input nor the version in order to make that happen. Can someone please help?

EDIT: I used to switch versions: `npm install -g cordova@3.3.1-0.4.2`

I couldn't find a listing of legacy versions on any phonegap site so I just searched Stack and found someone with a relatively close version. oh well, close enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `npm uninstall -g cordova` to uninstall then run `npm install -g cordova@3.3.0` to install version 3.3.

Comment: Should I do so at C:\ or can it be a project directory?

Comment: You can do it anywhere, you just have to use the `-g` flag to make it install globally. What exactly did it give you when it said it wasn't found?

Comment: It said that version didn't exist. So to test I installed 3.0.0 and that worked fine. So for some reason I needed the additional details for the version like the example I added to my question. If I remove the -g, am I able to update the version on the application level without changing the versions of other projects?

Comment: just to answer this, there are no cordova version @3.3.0 you can see the available versions  with  `npm view cordova versions`

Answer (score -1):

Simply give this command
npm install -g cordova@5.4.0
and your problem will be solved

Comment: I think, this isn't a correct answer. Because your command is supposed to install version 5.4.0 instead of version 3.3. Please note, that the OP explicitly wanted to switch back to an older version.